# Get DNS mapping from DNS Server in my Active Directory Domain (Windows)

Tags: dns, ip

I'm working in a company,
When I log on to my pc under Domain X, when I open a browser and put a URL www.someUrl.com it get resolved.

In a cloud machine Y I'm developing on, it does not get resolved, and I was wondering if there is some way of knowing how the mapping is done.

What I've tried:

1. Taking the IP address I'm getting from pinging successfully in machine X and ping it in machine Y.
2. Googling --> Didn't find nothing, guess I'm not searching for the problem correctly.
3. Contact my IT department --> The are busy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it turned out to be eventually, was that the machine I was trying to resolve was in the organization's intranet, that's why it could not be accessed from machine Y in the cloud which is public.

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing a few bits of information to fully determine the cause of this issue, but I can offer a few ideas/solutions:

1. When a host is under a domain, upon attempting to access a certain address by name, the host automatically attempts to resolve it both as entered and by adding the domain suffix to it (so someUrl.com will also be resolved as someUrl.com.domainName), so if, by any channce, this suffixed address is the real address, this could be the answer.
2. Another likely cause is the DNS server responsible for resolving your host's queries. If someUrl.com is not properly registered in global DNS servers and is only defined locally on your company's DNS, the cloud machine's DNS server will not be able to resolve the address.
3. One more option is that the domain is, in fact, resolved, but is not accessible from the cloud machine (either because of firewall configuration restricting the source of requests made to it, or because it is located behind the company's NAT, which your local machine does not have to go through to reach someUrl.com)

If none of these appear to be the cause of the problem, here's what you should do:

- `ipconfig /all` on both machines, to see what DNS server they are configured with
- `nslookup someUrl.com` from both machines, to see which DNS server answers the query
- if only the local host gets a proper nslookup response, try nslookup from the cloud using the host's DNS server (`nslookup someUrl.com <host DNS>`)
- ping the IP address of someUrl.com from both the host and the cloud (you said you performed this test, but you did not share the results :))

Comment: Thanks for your response, I actually forgot about this post. What it turned out to be eventually, was that the machine I was trying to resolve was in the organization's intranet, that's why it could not be accessed from machine Y in the cloud which is public.

Comment: Ah, that would be option number 3 :) The NAT separating the cloud from the inner organization network is what's blocking the communication (because it does not have port forwarding configured)